# Declaring Stage in external class function and using it in other class?

Tags: actionscript-3, positioning, stage

what I'm trying to achieve is making a "centerItem"-method that centers your object on the stage. I would like to add this method in my **Misc** class file, and use it everywhere in my application. I already tried it like below but this didn't work:

```
public static function centerItem(item:*):void
{
    item.x = (stage.stageWidth - item.width) >> 1;
    item.y = (stage.stageHeight - item.height) >> 1;
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
Misc.centerItem(myObjectToPlaceOnStage);
```

But when I try it out, it just gives me an error. I already looked on the web but I didn't find any constructive solutions. I hope someone might find a solution/hack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object is already added on the stage, you can access its stage property :

```
public static function centerItem(item:DisplayObject):void
{
    item.x = (item.stage.stageWidth - item.width) >> 1;
    item.y = (item.stage.stageHeight - item.height) >> 1;
}
```

By the way, I've typed your item parameter to `DisplayObject`, so you are sure that it has `width`, `height` and `stage` properties.

Comment: if(item.hasOwnProperty("stage"))
        {
            item.x = (item.stage.stageWidth - item.width) >> 1;
            item.y = (item.stage.stageHeight - item.height) >> 1;
        }

added the hasProperty, to be 100% sure it is added to stage (I'm not sure if this is the correct way but ok, still thanks ^^)

Comment: Nop. Don't use addOwnProperty, it will have the properties. You can check if it's on the stage with `item.stage != null` instead.